# Crash in Android 5 - IllegalStateException thrown inside onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-fragmentactivity

Recently we've been having crash reports in Crashlytics of an IllegalStateException that gets thrown when calling FramentTransaction.commit() inside the onResume method of our Activity. Strangely these crashes only occur in Android 4 and 5. The stack-trace is as follows:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2080)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2106)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
   ...
   at ...FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:597)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1267)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6186)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I've been trying hard to come up with a fix for the crash but ended up empty-handed. The way I see it, the only way this can happen is when onSaveInstanceState is called before onResume, but how is that even possible? Is there any way to replicate this behavior?

Comment: Installing leakcanary may help to understand if any leaks are causing the above as a sideeffect.

Comment: @ror I could do that, but what makes you think a memory leak could cause this side-effect?